# How to change antd Table header color

Tags: css, reactjs, components, antd, tableheader

I tried to target base classes as below which doesn't work.

```
.ant-table .ant-table-container .ant-table-content table thead.ant-table-thead {
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

Is there a working way to achieve this?
[image]

Corresponding JSX:

```
<Table columns={columns} dataSource={dataSource} />
```

Antd Table Docs: https://ant.design/components/table/

Comment: since `background: #fafafa;` is applyed to `.ant-table-thead>tr>th`, you can use `.ant-table-thead>tr>th {background-color: red;}`

Answer (score 8):

Background Color for Table Header is come from Table Cell. Try using below rule.

```
.ant-table-thead .ant-table-cell {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: This works
.ant-table
  .ant-table-container
  .ant-table-content
  table
  thead.ant-table-thead
  .ant-table-cell {
  background-color: green;
}

Comment: thank you, 
.ant-table-thead {
      background-color: green;
} 
this is not working actually with !important flag as well.
so this one .ant-table-thead .ant-table-cell work for me.

Answer (score 1):

use "!important"

```
  .ant-table-thead .ant-table-cell {
  background-color: green !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

### This works without `!important`

Antd default styles are highly specific. You need to target the element with more specificity to override default styles.

`!important` is not required with the below specificity.

```css
.ant-table
  .ant-table-container
  .ant-table-content
  table
  thead.ant-table-thead
  .ant-table-cell {
  background-color: green;
}
```